# Empty Structures compile in VB 10+

Tags: vb.net, structure

This is at least a documentation error, if not a bug.

In VB.NET prior to .NET 4.0 (i.e. VB.NET 7 through 9) an empty `Structure` declaration fails at compile-time with

> error BC30281: Structure 'MySimpleEmpty' must contain at least one instance member variable or Event declaration.

E.g. The following two structures compile successfully in VB10, and not prior:

```
Structure MySimpleEmpty
End Structure

Public Structure AnotherEmpty
  Public Const StillEmpty As Boolean = True
End Structure
```

I note the documentation for the [Error BC30281](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/csffdsdy.aspx) stops at VB9, but the documentation for the [Structure statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k69kzbs1.aspx) still has the *datamemberdeclarations* as required even as of VB11 (.NET 4.5 VS2012).

These two `Structures` compile in VB11 (VS2012) as well. <sub>(Thanks John Woo.)</sub>

Is there some blog entry or documentation confirming this is an intended change or a bug in VB10 and later?

Comment: It still compiles with visual studio 2012. I just tested it now.

Comment: You're right. This is a doc error on MSDN. I've submitted a note on the page so we'll see how efficient MS is in changing those pages :-)

Comment: @Mark, at the bottom of the page, there's a "did you find this helpful?" and this opens up a comment box. I'm still (re-)looking for my MS bug DB link, I haven't used it for a while.

Comment: Okay, got it - see https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/763191/doc-bug-empty-structures-allowed-in-vb-2012

Comment: I've also added it as "Commutity content" to the VB10 [Structure statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k69kzbs1(VS.100).aspx) description (with reference back to here).

Comment: @paxdiablo I've added a comment to your connect report, and noted I can reproduce it, but I can't quite say I see it as "important" :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft have marked this as a fixed bug, without actually stating what was fixed.

The VB11 (VS2012) documentation now says the *datamemberdeclarations* are optional in the grammar, but in the Parts table it says "Required. Zero or more..."!

I guess that's a fix...  The VB10 (VS2010) documentation hasn't been changed.